# Difference between $form_state['values'] and $form_state['input']

Tags: forms

Can someone please tell me the difference between these two variables?

```
$form_state['values']
$form_state['input']
```

Optionally some example of action they are used with. I'm wondering especially about using with ajax in drupal form. Which of these should I use in ajax callback to get input values from the form?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The crucial difference here is that in most cases you should be using $form_state['values']; since the data on the $form_state['input'] array is raw and unvalidated.

$form_state['input'] is useful for multi-step forms, assuming you are familiar with how to safely handle raw input.... See [form_builder](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_builder/7) for more information...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know what you are doing, you `$form_state['values']` it is the processed form values. `$form_state['input']` is the raw data. See the code for form_builder: [https://api.drupal.org/api....](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_builder/7)

Answer (score 0):

`$form_state['values']` should be uses in most of the cases as `$form_state['input']` hold the raw and invalidated value. Also in `$form_state['values']` default values are passed when submission of form fails, but in case of `$form_state['input']` NULL is passed.

Answer (score 0):

In 99.9% of cases, `$form_state['values']` and `$form_state['input']` are identical.

But -- beware of a portion of the 1%, particularly when using the **date_popup** field, as it's input is stored in 'input', but NOT in the 'values' array.

Answer (score -5):

In the [drupal_form_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7) function, you can see the following code :

```
// Populate $form_state['input'] with the submitted values before retrieving
// the form, to be consistent with what drupal_build_form() does for
// non-programmatic submissions (form builder functions may expect it to be
// there).
$form_state['input'] = $form_state['values'];
```

So it is exactly the same.

Comment: Above function is used to programatically submit form... It doesn't answer OP Question..